# DayofYear + Curdate not working

Tags: php, mysql, date

I cant get the dayofyear and curdate to work.

If I remove it, the code works but I need the condition.

The error message is "Trying to get property of non-object "

```
                <?php
            $rowhtipoo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_articles WHERE bog_id=1 AND  fk_publish_dato_id = DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE());") or die(mysql_error());
            $rwhtip=mysql_fetch_object($rowhtipoo);
            ?>
            <div class="tipet">
            <p><span class="f vvv"><?php nl2br($rwhtip->english_navn);?></span></p>
            <p><?php echo nl2br($rwhtip->english_tekst);?></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Run your query in phpmyadmin and see if returns errors,if it return null then before getting objects check for not empty `if(!empty(rwhtip)) { your code }`

Comment: Please post the definition and some sample values for your `fk_publish_dato_id` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like a result isn't found and mysql_fetch_object is returning a false value. Maybe you'd have better luck doing something like the example below.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php.

```
    <?php   while ( $rwhtip = mysql_fetch_array($rowhtipoo) ) { ?>
        <div class="tipet">
            <p>
                <span class="f vvv">
                    <?php echo nl2br($rwhtip["english_navn"]);?></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo nl2br($rwhtip["english_tekst"]);?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let PHP take care of the date?

```
$rowhtipoo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_articles WHERE bog_id=1 AND fk_publish_dato_id = '" . date('Y-m-d') . "';") or die(mysql_error());
```

Or, it can be a typo - fk_publish_datO_id ?

Comment: Thanks for the help and dato = date in Danish, so no typo :-)